# Is it possible to get a virus/malware infection from opening a 7-zip (.7z) file?

Tags: virus, malware, 7-zip

Title says it all.

In particular, is there any step in the 7-zip decompression process that could allow code execution?

Comment: All complex file Formats have this (Low) Risk. Archivers, Image Metadata, colorprofiles, Video encoding, Sound Tags, scripting in PDF, office files or html and so on are known to exploit weaknesses. Typically it is a parser buffer overflow, but having stupid logic executing commands or overwriting random files is not unheared of.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Potentially yes - if you do not have a very, very recent version of 7-Zip.  There was an "out-of-bounds read vulnerability" which could be exploited to run arbitrary code, and also another heap overflow vulnerability.  CVE-2018-5996 and [CVE-2017-17969](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2018-5996/) - January 2018 could be exploited to run arbitrary code, and there is an even worse problem dating back to 2016.

Also see [this](https://landave.io/2018/01/7-zip-multiple-memory-corruptions-via-rar-and-zip/) blog post.